# Migrating C# solution from Visual Studio 2005 to 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vb6, com-interop

I need to use a solution built in VS 2005. But I only have VS 2012 to deal with.

The solution is all fine with VS 2005 as I know, but when I tried to open it in 2012, several problems existed.

After searching and resolving most of them, including signing many strong names into one .snk, modifying some coding for VS2012, registering score.dll with `regsvr32` and so on, I can finally run the solution in debug mode without error.

However, when I input some information into the main forms in order to trigger some calculation, an error occurs and seems related to score.dll which was built in VB6.

> Business Logic Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Score, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5ce8a8a190705d24' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

How to deal with it? As I do not have admin rights to do some of the steps, I need to confirm what steps I should do and ask for help from administrator.

Comment: If it's a com dll, you might need to register it with regsvr32 before it can be called by anything.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx

Comment: Also assuming you are dealing with a vb6 comm dll dependency, your .net solution will need to target x86 (not any cpu) as you won't be able to load a 32bit com dll in a 64 bit or any cpu process (if the environment is 64 bit) and will need to directly target x86 (32 bit).

Comment: for regsvr32, I have already done that.

Comment: For x86 issue, I have already tried before as there are also some suggestion like that in the internet. However when I change all the program from any cpu to x86, the following error and warning message occurs eg, Warning 5 Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "...Score.dll". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit. Forms

Comment: And some other error occurs like Referenced assembly '...GenCode128.dll' is not a valid assembly, Referenced assembly '...PComm.dll' is not a valid assembly and so on

Comment: @Andy02181991 When you are building against x86 you have to make sure Score.dll is in the 32 bit registry because that's where the program will look when it's compiled in x86.  This means you have to use the regsvr32.exe from the Windows/SysWow64/ folder when registering the dll.